# How to encrypt and decrypt a large file using the AES-CBC algorithm with encryption progress/status indicator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, aes

I'm using nodejs built-in crypto, zlib and fs package to encrypt a large file using these codes.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import zlib from 'zlib';
import crypto from 'crypto';

const initVect = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const fread = fs.createReadStream('X:/File.mp4');
const fwrite = fs.createWriteStream('X:/File.mp4.enc');
const gzipStream = zlib.createGzip();
const hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('SomePassword').digest();
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(
    'aes-256-cbc',
    hashedPassword,
    initVect
);

fread.pipe(gzipStream).pipe(cipher).pipe(fwrite);
```

But I don't know how to add an encryption progress/status indicator, since a large file will take a lot of time to encrypt I want to show encryption progress to the user in the console.

Can you guys tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using stream `Transform()`. Create a new stream `Transform()`, get the processed chunk length in it, then simply calculate progress with chunk length and file size, then add this new transform to your existing pipe.

Like this:-

```
import fs from 'fs';
import zlib from 'zlib';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { TransformCallback, Transform } from 'stream';

const initVect = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const fread = fs.createReadStream('X:/File.mp4');
const fwrite = fs.createWriteStream('X:/File.mp4.enc');
const gzipStream = zlib.createGzip();
const hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('SomePassword').digest();
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(
    'aes-256-cbc',
    hashedPassword,
    initVect
);

const fileSize = fs.statSync(fread.path).size;
let processedBytes = 0;
const progressPipe = new Transform({
    transform(
        chunk: Buffer,
        _encoding: BufferEncoding,
        callback: TransformCallback
    ) {
        processedBytes += chunk.length;
        console.log(
            `${Math.floor((processedBytes / fileSize) * 100)}%`
        );
        this.push(chunk);
        callback();
    },
});

fread.pipe(progressPipe).pipe(gzipStream).pipe(cipher).pipe(fwrite);
```